# Import files in python

Tags: python, django, module, python-import

I know it's possible to import everything in a file into another file like this:

```
from app1.models import *
```

But I want to do something like this:

```
from *.models import *
```

It means import everything inside models file from any directory.

for example in this file structure

```
/module
    /app1
        /models.py
    /app2
        /models.py
    /allModels.py
```

I want to import all models.py files into allModels.py

Is it possible? Do we have such syntax?

Comment: There is no such way

Comment: Django detects models inside app well-registered in `settings.INSTALLED_APPS`, by doing what you want, how Django will suppose to detect your models, also changes? why do you want to do that?

Comment: No, there isn't. Note, [starred imports are considered bad practice generally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386714/why-is-import-bad?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa). It's good that what you are trying to do isn't allowed, because it would almost certainly be abused.

Comment: how about, reading the list of all .py files using os.listdir and use a loop to import them all?